# React-router link doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React-router is off to a really bad start... What seems basic doesn't work. Using react-router 2.0.0 my Link component updates the URL to be /about, but my page doesn't render the About component after that...

**Entry point js**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var hashHistory = require('react-router').hashHistory;
var App = require('./components/App.react');
var About = require('./components/About');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory} >
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
        </Route>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**App.js**

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
var Header = require('./Header');
var UserPanel = require('./UserPanel');
var ModelPanel = require('./ModelPanel.react');
var EventPanel = require('./event/EventPanel');
var VisPanel = require('./vis/VisPanel');
var LoginForm = require('./LoginForm');
var AppStore = require('../stores/AppStore');
var AppStates = require('../constants/AppStates');

var App = React.createClass({

  [... code omitted ...]

  render: function() {
    var viewStateUi = getViewStateUi(this.state.appState);

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        {viewStateUi}
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the 'About' route is a child of the 'App' route, you need to either add `this.props.children` to your App component:

```
var App = React.createClass({

 render: function() {

   var viewStateUi = getViewStateUi(this.state.appState);

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Link href="/about">About</Link>
        {viewStateUi}
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

or separate your routes:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory} >
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  </Router>, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll test tonight and read all the docs - that's pretty obvious in retrospect.

Comment: It works, but I don't why it works by adding '{this.props.children}' in App. Why without it, it doesn't work ? Please

Answer (score 13):

For some reason, the `<Link>`s were not working for me with the configuration below.

// index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter >
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

// App.js

```
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <Route exact={true} path="/:lang" component={Home} />
        <Route exact={true} path="/" render={() => <Redirect to={{ pathname: 'pt' }} />} />
        <Route path="/:lang/play" component={Play} />} />
        <Route path="/:lang/end" component={End} />
      </div >
    );
```

The Home component had the Link, but Links on the App would do the same. Every time I clicked it, it would only change the url, but the views would stay the same.

I was able to put it working when I added **withRouter** to the App.js

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { f, g })(App));
```

I still don't understand what happened. Maybe it's related with redux or there is some detail I'm missing.

Comment: You were right it is related to Redux be cause I've just had the same problem with MobX. The thing is that MobX/Redux takes control of `shouldComponentUpdate` so the `App` component does not re-render be cause it does not receive the `location` as a prop. More explanations in the documentation here : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me, including adding `withRouter` to my Component. I was experiencing the same issue where the browser's address bar updates the URL but the component doesn't render. During the debugging of my issue, I realize I have to present the context of my problem because it is a bit different from what the OP had.

The route I was trying to get to work was a dynamic route that takes an arbitrary parameter, e.g.

```
<Route path={`/hr/employees/:id`} component={EmployeePage} />
```

The component this route uses is "self-referential", meaning that within the component or its children components, they have a `Link` component that directs to `/hr/employees/:id`, but with a different id. So let's say if I was at `/hr/employees/3` and on the page, there was a link to `/hr/employees/4`, e.g. `<Link to='/hr/employees/4'>`, I would get this problem where the component didn't re-render.

To solve this problem, I simply modified the `componentDidUpdate` method of my `EmployeePage` component:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.match.params.id !== prevProps.match.params.id) {
    // fetch data
  }
}
```

If you're using functional components, use `useEffect`:

```
const EmployeePage = props => {
  const {id} = props.match.params
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch data
  }, [id])
}
```